# Why is there whitespace separating list items from its parentr?

Tags: html, css

This is my first time implementing the standard html nav. However, the list elements inside nav are not positioned inside nav the way I want them to be, and although I've changed most of the obvious properties that come to mind, I haven't been able to:

- Center the li elements inside nav
- Make the width of the li elements fit perfectly inside nav

I don't understand why they are by default positioned so awkwardly to the right of their parent container, or why setting 'width: 100%' isn't the solution. When I set the positioning on the li elements to absolute, it seems to mucks up everything since I need each list element to be positioned relative to where the element before it is placed.

There seems to be a few possible ways I could go about solving this problem, but they seem sort of hackish, and I'm wondering if there's a more obvious solution I lack the experience to see.

```css
nav {
  width: 40%; height: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black; 
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none; text-align: center;
  width: 99%; height: 100%;
  position: inherit;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav><!--
  --><ul><!--
   --><li class="user">WelcomeVids</li>
      <li class="user">Diablo</li>
      <li class="user">FreeCodeCamp</li>
      <li class="user">OtherStuff</li>
      <li class="user">Dota2</li><!--
  --></ul><!--
--></nav>
```

To see the output, view my Codepen: http://codepen.io/sentedelviento/full/grzrgR/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because most browsers default to adding a `padding-left` to `<ul>`. You can override that:

```css
/* Added */
ul {
  padding-left: 0;
}

nav {
  width: 40%; height: 500px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black; 
}

nav ul li {
  list-style: none; text-align: center;
  /* width: 99%; height: 100%; */
  position: inherit;
  padding: 1%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  margin: 0;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<nav><!--
  --><ul><!--
   --><li class="user">WelcomeVids</li>
      <li class="user">Diablo</li>
      <li class="user">FreeCodeCamp</li>
      <li class="user">OtherStuff</li>
      <li class="user">Dota2</li><!--
  --></ul><!--
--></nav>
```

Comment: This completely solved my problem that I described.
However, setting width to 100% does not work, as the padding is set to 1%, so I set it to 99%. However, the border is set to 2px, any way to know how to take that into account when determining width percent?

Comment: @AllisonStafford If I'm understanding you correctly, then I don't think you need `width: 100%`. You already have `display: block` on your `li`s, which will make them as wide as their parent. You'll notice that I also took out the `height: 100%` on the `li`s because it wasn't doing anything.

Comment: Also, it could be good to take a look at [CSS resets](http://cssreset.com/what-is-a-css-reset/). They're designed for issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the following changes to your CSS:

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul li {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: auto;
}
```